# UITableView not updating

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

I'm using a Core Data model and a UITableViewController table view. My model seems to be working quite well however my table view is not updating when I add an entity to my model. The reason I believe my model is working is because when I add an entity nothing shows up in the view during run time, however if I cut the task then start it up new, suddenly the entity I previously created shows up in the table view.

Here is my table view controller - AudioTableViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Bank.h"
#import "Player.h"

@class Player;
@interface AudioTableViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    Player *myMainMan;
}

-(void)addAudioEntityToArray:(AudioFile *)event;
-(NSMutableArray *)recordingsArray;

@end
```

AudioTableViewController.m (implementation file)

```
#import "AudioTableViewController.h"

@implementation AudioTableViewController

-(void)addAudioEntityToArray:(AudioFile *)event {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath;

    if(event.type) {
        [[MusikerViewController recordingsArray] addObject:event];//self?
        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    }else {
        [[MusikerViewController downloadsArray] addObject:event];
        indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1];
    }

     [[self tableView] setEditing:YES animated:NO];
     [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                      withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone]; 
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [[self tableView] reloadData];
      [super viewDidLoad];

      self.title = @"Audio Files";//put this in application delegate

      self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.    

    NSLog(@"Place I");

    if(section == 0) {
        return [[MusikerViewController recordingsArray] count];
    } else if (section == 1) {
        return [[MusikerViewController downloadsArray] count];
    }
}
```

... more methods

Here is part of my Bank class that might be relevant
Bank.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>
#import "AudioFile.h"
#import "AudioTableViewController.h"
#import "MusikerAppDelegate.h"

@interface Bank : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate> {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    AudioFile *sound;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext   *managedObjectContext;

+(NSString *)getDataPath:(NSString *)fileExtDate;

-(AudioFile *)addAudioFileEntityToModelWithDate:(NSDate *)theD andURLString:(NSString *)str;
-(BOOL)removeAudioFromModel:(id)audio;
-(NSMutableArray *)getFetchArray;

@end
```

Bank.m

```
#import "Bank.h"

@implementation Bank
@synthesize managedObjectContext;

- (AudioFile *)addAudioFileEntityToModelWithDate:(NSDate *)theD andURLString:(NSString *)str {
     sound = (AudioFile *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AudioFile" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

     sound.creationDate = theD;
     sound.soundPath = str; //set the sound path to the sound file's url
     [self alertForTitle];

     return sound;
}

- (BOOL)saveContext {
    NSError *error = nil;
    if(!managedObjectContext) {
        NSLog(@"managedObejctContext problem at saveContext Bank");
    }

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}

- (NSMutableArray *)getFetchArray {

    NSLog(@"ManagedObjectContext at getFetchArray");
    NSLog(@"Context: %@",managedObjectContext);

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    if(!managedObjectContext) {
        NSLog(@"There is no managedObjectContext in getFetchArray Bank");
    }
       NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AudioFile" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    [sortDescriptor release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil) {
        NSLog(@"mutableFetchResults array is nil");
    } 
    [request release];
    return mutableFetchResults;
}

+ (NSString *)getDataPath:(NSString *)fileExtDate {

    NSLog(@"getDataPath called");

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Musik Directory"];         //changing the recording directory to Musik Directory

    NSError *error;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:documentsDirectory]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&error]; 
        NSLog(@"In the if statement");
    }

    NSString *docPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileExtDate];

    return docPath;

}
```

Player.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import "Bank.h"

@class Bank;
@interface Player : NSObject <AVAudioPlayerDelegate, AVAudioRecorderDelegate> {

Bank *daBank;

AVAudioPlayer *musicPlayer;
AVAudioRecorder *musicRecorder;

NSDate *myDate;
NSString *strPath;

NSString *documentPath_;
NSMutableArray *arrayListOfRecordSound;
}

-(void)playSoundFile:(NSString *)soundFilePath;
-(BOOL)saveRecordingWithDate:(NSDate *)theD andURLString:(NSString *)str;
-(void)recordSomething;
-(void)playRecording;
-(void)play;

+ (NSString *)dateString:(NSDate *)date;
+ (NSString *)dateString;

@end
```

Player.m

```
- (Bank *)daBank 
{    
    if(!daBank) {
        daBank = [[Bank alloc] init];
    }

    return daBank;
}

-(BOOL)saveRecording { //this is the method that adds the new object to both the //model and view, the method that calls this method is not shown
    Bank *B = [MusikerViewController daBank];
    AudioTableViewController *ATVC2 = [MusikerViewController ATVControl];
    AudioFile *myAudioFileMusicX314 = [[B addAudioFileEntityToModelWithDate:myDate andURLString:strPath] retain];

    myAudioFileMusicX314.type = true;

    [ATVC2 addAudioEntityToArray:myAudioFileMusicX314]; 

    if(![B saveContext]) { 
        NSLog(@"addAudioFileEntityToModel is returning a nil managedObjectContext");
        return NO;
    }

    [myDate release];
    [strPath release];
    [myAudioFileMusicX314 release];
[ATVC2 release];

    return YES;            
}
```

Last but not least, MusikViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Player.h"
#import "Bank.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "MyButtonView.h"
#import "AudioTableViewController.h"

@class AudioTableViewController;
@class Bank;
@class Player;
@interface MusikerViewController : UIViewController {
]    BOOL *pressed;
}

Player *myMainMan;
Bank   *daBank;
AudioTableViewController *ATVControl;
NSMutableArray   *recordingsArray;
NSMutableArray   *downloadsArray;

+ (Bank *)daBank;
+ (Player *)myMainMan;
+ (AudioTableViewController *)ATVControl;
+ (NSMutableArray *)recordingsArray;
+ (NSMutableArray *)downloadsArray;

@end
```

MusikViewController.m

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)recordingsArray {
    NSLog(@"recordingsArray called");

    if(!recordingsArray) {
        recordingsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *bigTempArray = [[[[Bank alloc] init] autorelease] getFetchArray]; //change this
        for(AudioFile *af in bigTempArray)
            if(af.type) {
                [recordingsArray addObject:af];
            }
        NSLog(@"recordingsArray exists");
    }
    return recordingsArray;
}

+ (NSMutableArray *)downloadsArray {
    NSLog(@"recordingsArray called");

    if(!downloadsArray) {
        downloadsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        // if(!bigTempArray)
        NSMutableArray *bigTempArray = [[[[Bank alloc] init] autorelease] getFetchArray];
        for(AudioFile *af in bigTempArray)
            if(!af.type) {
                [downloadsArray addObject:af];
            }
    }
    return downloadsArray;
}
```

If there are any more methods that might be relevant, let me know and I will happily post them.

I should also mention that, I can add a single entity to the array after I launch the app, but after that its the same problem.

Comment: post your `numberOfRows` method

Comment: Is addAudioEntityToArray performed on the main thread?

Comment: at least as far as i know. It should be.

Comment: Try this `[self.tableView beginUpdates];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
        [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                              withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
       [self.tableView endUpdates];`

Comment: batching the methods didnt work

Comment: Try to `NSLog eventsArray` in method `addAudioEntityToArray`.

Comment: the first time addAudioEntityToArray eventsArray is null! 

Im going to check that out, hopefully thats where the problem lies!

Comment: offtopic: i highly recommend you to read the ObjC Code Styleguide from the NYTimes: https://github.com/NYTimes/objective-c-style-guide?source=c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is the architecture of your view controllers. Try this:

1) Set up all the core data stack in the app delegate. Pass the associated managed object context to all your view controllers as a property. That is the pattern Apple uses in many of its sample code examples.

2) For each table view controller, create **its own** `NSFetchedResultsController`, normally also as a property. Use the Apple samples as a guide.

3) **Never** fetch any data from another view controller, as you do in your code. You cannot and should not get the table data for the `AudioTableViewController` from the `MusikerViewController`.

It is possible and sometimes useful to have a central data object that provides data to view controllers. You cannot have this data object be a view controller. This is a blatant (and in your case fatal) violation of the MVC design pattern. Your error most likely stems from that (because `MusikerViewController` is not on screen and may even be deallocated).

4) Make sure that in your `datasource` methods you use **only** the fetched results controller to populate the tables and deliver media.

Comment: Can you provide some actual code. I want to make sure I do exactly what you're suggesting so I know if it works or not

Comment: Start with a new project (master detail) and check "Core Data". Just copy paste.

Comment: which class should keep the recordingsArray and downloadsArray and should I declare them as properties?

Comment: Also, I use my MusikViewController as a getter for my Bank and Player. When I create an instance of Bank or Player, should I get the instance from MusikViewController, or should I just alloc init an instance of Bank and Player directly when I want to call them?

Comment: Don't use any of these arrays. Use Core Data (i.e. a fetched results controller). This eliminates the need of arrays. It is because of these unnecessary complications and redundancies that your table is not updating.

Answer (score 5):

May be your - (void)addAudioEntityToArray:(AudioFile *)event {} method is called from secondary thread (other than MainUi thread) so that directly reloading table will not work.

try instead

```
[self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

Hope it Helps!!

Comment: just paste this over [self.tableView reloadData]?

Comment: i tried pasting ur code over [self.tableView reloadData] but it didnt make any difference.

Comment: try remove  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];   
   [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
 and then add reload method.

Comment: I have updated the problem, I think it might be easier to solve now

Comment: So ur line of code has helped. It keeps the app from erroring out, but for some reason the table view still isnt being updated. If i havnt already mentioned, I am adding ovjects to the table view from another, seperate view controller

Answer (score 1):

Add `[self.tableView reloadData]` into `addAudioEntityToArray` method at the end. This will force the UITableView to reload from the model after each insertion.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting eventsArray via setter:

```
[self setEventsArray:[daBank getFetchArray]];
```

Why don't you access it via getter? You might be using another instance of array

`self.eventsArray` or `[self eventsArray]`

Comment: that might make the code a little more readable but it didnt fix the problem. Thanks anyway tho

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a fetchresultscontroller, I used arrays before, but much better with FRC.

Comment: Ill try that, but the array im getting from the NSFetchResult is the correct array with all the right info so i would b kinda surprised if the problem was there, but u never knoe, ill definatly give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: I didnt find any different results

Answer (score 0):

In your `addAudioEntityToArray` method your call to `addObject` will add the new event to the **END** of the array, not the beginning.

Therefor the indexPath that you need to send to `insertRowsAtIndexPaths` is: like `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[MusikerViewController recordingsArray].count-1 inSection:0]`