# Load new data in table when view appears

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

In my project, I have a mechanism for adding/displaying/editing contacts, in a similar fashion to the address book app. I use core data for the data management. Basically, when the app loads, all my current contacts are there, but when I add a new contact and return to the table view of all the contacts, I dont see changes. Then when I close the application and open it again, the changes are visible. Can some one please let me know what I am doing wrong? I would like it to refresh after adding a new contact.

allathletes.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(addAthlete)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *athlete = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Athlete" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:athlete];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"first" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil){
        //handle error
    }
    [self setAthleteArray:mutableFetchResults];


    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}


-(void)addAthlete{
    AthleteAdd *addAthlete= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"addAthlete"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:addAthlete animated:YES];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Athlete Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Athlete *athlete = (Athlete *)[athleteArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = [athlete first];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [athlete last];
    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
```

addathlete.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    UIBarButtonItem *saveButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(saveAthlete)];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(cancelSave)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
}

-(void)saveAthlete{
    Athlete *athlete = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Athlete" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [athlete setFirst:firstTextField.text];
    [athlete setLast:lastTextField.text];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if(![_managedObjectContext save:&error]){
        //handle dat error
    }
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

-(void)cancelSave{

    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: same problem here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17940662/uitableviewcontroller-not-updating

Comment: try to reload the table with new datasource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Athlete gets added to the persistence store but your table is not showing you the updated data. After adding the new Athlete object, fetch the updated data from persistence store to the AthleteArray(STEP 1) and reload your table view (STEP 2).

STEP 1:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *athlete = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Athlete" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
    [request setEntity:athlete];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"first" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
    [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil){
        //handle error
    }
    [self setAthleteArray:mutableFetchResults];
```

STEP 2:

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

**reload** the `tabelView` in `viewDidAppear:` OR `viewWillAppear:` method. `viewDidLoad:` method doesn't call at the time of `pop` and `dismiss`. Thats why the updates are not visible in the `tableView`.